# How to clear an attribute that was setAttribute('onclick', 'window.open()') in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension that creates a **div** on the page. Later on, this **div** gets updated to open a new tab:

```
var div = document.getElementById("MyReport");
div.setAttribute('onclick', "window.open('" + results.productUrl + "')");
```

The link can get updated a few times. Each time it gets updated, the previous `onclick` action stays. I can't seem to clear the previous `onclick`. I tried:

```
var div = document.getElementById("MyReport");
div.removeAttribute('onclick');
div.setAttribute('onclick', "window.open('" + results.productUrl + "')");
```

But each time this gets updated, it still opens every link I ever associated. So when user finally clicks on the **div**, it opens up 10-20 tabs instead of just the most recent link.

I would expect that setAttribute would just overwrite the previous value, but not even removeAttribute seems to be working. When I 'inspect' the page, there is still just one **div** named 'MyReport', and it only has one 'onclick'.

**FULL EXAMPLE** (Chrome Extension)

*To use, put both manifest.json and amazon.user.js into a directory. Then under Chrome settings, enable "Developer Mode". Click on "Load Unpacked Extension" and navigate to the folder you saved the files in.*

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "AmazonLink",
  "version": "0.001",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Adds link to Amazon page",
  "icons": {
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://www.amazon.com/*"
        ],
      "js": ["amazon.user.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

amazon.user.js:

```
function addAmazonLink() {
    // Page example: Baby K'tan Original Baby Carrier amazon.com/dp/B00FSKX266
    var element = document.getElementById('price_feature_div');
    var siblingToPlaceBefore = element.firstChild;
    if (element == null || siblingToPlaceBefore == null) return false;
    var fsDiv = document.createElement('div');
    fsDiv.setAttribute('style', 'text-decoration: none; text-align: center; border-radius: 5px;  position: relative; margin-bottom: 4px;padding:4px;max-width:270px');
    element.insertBefore(fsDiv, siblingToPlaceBefore);
    fsDiv.setAttribute('id', "MyLinkDiv");
    var txt = document.createTextNode("Click Me!");
    fsDiv.appendChild(txt);
    UpdateLink();
    return true;

}

function UpdateLink(num){
    var strLink = encodeURI("https://www.google.com?q=" + num);

    var div = document.getElementById("MyLinkDiv");
    if (div == null) {
        return;
    }

    div.removeAttribute('onclick'); // This shouldn't matter
    div.setAttribute('onclick', "window.open('" + strLink + "')");

    return true;
}

addAmazonLink();
setTimeout(function() {
    UpdateLink(1);
}, 500);
setTimeout(function() {
    UpdateLink(2);
}, 1500);
setTimeout(function() {
    UpdateLink(3);
}, 2500);
setTimeout(function() {
    UpdateLink(4);
}, 3500);
```

After navigating to [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00FSKX266](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00FSKX266), you will see a "Click me!" above the Add to Cart button. Wait a few seconds, then click it. Several Google pages will open instead of just the expected 1. *Note that different products on Amazon use different CSS classes/ids, so while the example will run on the B00FSKX266 product above, it may not run for other Amazon product pages*

Comment: What you're describing doesn't happen just with that information ([proof](https://jsfiddle.net/j4f37jsa/)), so there must be something you've accidentally left out. Please put a [mcve] in the question using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) demonstrating the issue (at least for those of us using Chrome), so we can help you.

Comment: Don't use `setAttribute` to add event handlers, use `addEventListener`.

Comment: _"So when user finally clicks on the div, it opens up 10-20 tabs instead of just the most recent link."_ Cannot reproduce.

Comment: I have updated the question with a full working minimal-ish example. Just put both files into a directory (as explained) and navigate to the Amazon product page mentioned.

Comment: I wonder if JavaScript in extensions work differently than script on the page. I see your examples are not able to reproduce this, but when I use the example I pasted above as an extension, it reproduces the issue.

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using? Using Chrome 55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit) and the code you have provided, I do not see the same behavior as you report. On the other hand, I do see what I would consider a bug in Chrome. When clicked, only one tab is opened. However, the `onclick` attribute value that is used used is the *first one assigned* `https://www.google.com?q=undefined`, not the last one `window.open('https://www.google.com?q=4')` When the element is inspected with DevTools, or the `onclick` attribute is read back using `getAttribute()` the value is the last one assigned.

Comment: When the exact same code is used as a Firefox WebExtension, and the `<div>` clicked, the last `onclick` attribute which is assigned `window.open('https://www.google.com?q=4')` is used. This definitely looks like a bug in Chrome.

Comment: I'm on 55.0.2883.87 m. Strange that it behaves differently for us. I have filed a ticket at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=677769

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your code didn't work is because you added an attribute to `div` on page load.

```
div.setAttribute('onclick', "window.open('" + results.productUrl + "')");
```

It basically translates to

`<div onclick="window.open('http://someurl.com/')"></div>`

So, the solution is to add `window.open(url)` on click event.

```
var div = document.getElementById("MyReport");
var results = {productUrl: 'http://stackoverflow.com'};
div.addEventListener('click', function() {

    // Generating random url for demo 
    // "?test=" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000 + 1)
    // Write your logic to add url

    url = results.productUrl + "?test=" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000 + 1);
    window.open( url );
});
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bzz7op2v/)

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Hey thanks Rajender! I'm still not sure why chrome sees one 'onclick', yet opens 10-20 tabs. But changing to use an event listener works great!